# How to use dynamic routing to pass information / react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic-routing

The `ButtonList` returns a list of filtered `Buttons` that should each link to a new page. I would like to do it by adding dynamic routes, but I don't know how to write the code... How do I use history.push correctly? Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
export default function Home() {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  const filteredData = data.filter(item =>
    item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
  );

  function handleSearch(value) {
    setSearchValue(value);
  }

  const selectedItem = filteredData.find(item => item.name);

  function handleSelect(item) {
    history.push(`/home/${item.name}`);
  }

  return (
    <WrapperDiv>
      <StyledHeader />
      <Switch>
              
        <Route exact path="/home">
                
          <Searchbar onSearch={handleSearch} />
          <ButtonList data={filteredData} onClick={handleSelect} /> 
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/home/{...}">
          <StyledDiv>
            <Button item={selectedItem} light />
            <AccordionList />
          </StyledDiv>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </WrapperDiv>
  );
}
```

```
export default function Button({ children, handleSelect }) {
  return (
    <button
      to={{
        pathname: "/home/" + data.name,
        data: data
      }}
      onClick={handleSelect}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

```
export const data = [
  {
    name: "Apple",
    id: 1 
  },
  {
    name: "Banana",
    id: 2 
  },
  {
    name: "Blueberry",
    id: 3 
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

one good way to achieve it would be to use [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) which makes creating dynamic routes really easy.

Writing the whole code is a little difficult here, therefore [I found a good example of an easy way to implement react-router](https://learnwithparam.com/blog/dynamic-pages-in-react-router/) with your code.

**Example**

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function MyButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function triggerClick() {
    history.push("/somewhere");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={triggerClick}>
      Go somewhere
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I want to do, but I can't make it work for my scenario. I want to post item.name to the url (instead of index+1 here: <Link to={`/user/${index + 1}`}>) - how could I do that?

Comment: as far as I can tell, your code is fine. if you imported `useHistory();` from react-router, then it should work. can you maybe give a little more info about the problem you're having?